# How can I color a specific day with specific time with slotPropGetter of react-big-calendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, react-big-calendar

I have a [react-big-calendar](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-components) and I want to get same informations like the day and the start and the end (as a time) for coloring the time and the day slot with slotPropGetter.

My informations from the backend is:

```
    {   "start": "2019-08-23T13:30:00",
        "end": "2019-08-23T18:00:00",
        "rendering": "background",
        "color": "#f740f7"
    }
```

I try with `slotPropGetter` :

```
slotPropGetter={
                (date) => {
                    for(let i =0; i<this.state.eventsPlanning.length; i++) {
                      if(this.state.eventsPlanning[i].rendering === 'background') {
                        let newStyle ={
                          backgroundColor:'red'
                        }
                        return {
                          className: "rbc-day-slot rbc-time-slot",
                          style: newStyle
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

when I run it, it seems all the days are colored, but I want just to color according the `start` and the `end` of the informations.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `slotPropGetter` method is called when rendering each individual `timeslot` in the `Day` and `Week` views, and the `date` object passed is a full date/time js `Date` object for the *starting time* of the slot. How many times this method is called, per hour long block in these views, is determined by your calendar's `step` and `timeslots` properties. So, for instance, the default `step` is `30` and `timeslots` is `2`, which will pass a date with `HH:00` and `HH:30` the two times it is called (`HH` being the actual 24 hour `hour`). If you changed this to a `step` of `15` and `timeslots` of `4` the method will be called four times every hour, incrementing fifteen minutes each time. You would have to use your own date math to then determine which slot cells are being adjusted.

Comment: Thank you @Steve